# Can you insert into a HashMap in a way the gives you an owned copy of the key if an entry is present?

Tags: rust

[Rust's `HashMap::insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.insert)
takes `(K, V)` and returns an (owned) `V` if an entry was already present. In this case, there should also be an (owned) key in the existing entry. Is there a way to get it?

i.e. is there a way to implement something like `HashMap::insert_entry(&mut self, k: K, v: V) -> Option(K, V)>`?

I see that you could do `HashMap::remove_entry` followed by `HashMap::insert`, but this requires two lookups. I believe this should only require one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`HashMap::entry` and its variants](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#variants), along with the [`map_entry_replace`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44286) feature:

```rust
#![feature(map_entry_replace)]

fn insert_entry<K: Hash + Eq, V>(m: &mut HashMap<K, V>, k: K, v: V) -> Option<(K, V)> {
    match m.entry(k) {
        Entry::Occupied(o) => {
            Some(o.replace_entry(v))
        }
        Entry::Vacant(va) => {
            va.insert(v);
            None
        }
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9599f027b4697dcf7a2a0e83cd1b7d39)

Comment: Thanks @apatniv! Your advice to explicitly use the variants of `hash_map::Entry` was spot on.

I've edited your solution to handle ownership correctly. The edits should be visible once someone approves them.